# Regex to match two hyphens in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

I am a XSLT newbie, would like to get regex to match this pattern.

```
String1-number-String2
```

I need to capture the substring before the second hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example replace function:

```
<!-- this will return "number" -->
<xsl:value-of select="replace('String1-number-String2', '(.*)-(.*)-(.*)', '$2')" />

<!-- this will return "String1-number" -->
<xsl:value-of select="replace('String1-number-String2', '(.*)-(.*)-(.*)', '$1-$2')" />
<xsl:value-of select="replace('String1-number-String2', '(.*-.*)-(.*)', '$1')" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick responses. Really appreciate your help. Please suggest a good book to learn xslt regex.

Comment: @user2461078 - Michael Kay's "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference" (4th edition) is a great book that includes an entire chapter on regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replace()` with the regex `^([^-]+-[^-]+).*`.

Example...

**XML**

```
<test>String1-number-String2</test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <results>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'^([^-]+-[^-]+).*','$1')"/>         
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>String1-number</results>
```

Comment: My answer is very similar to Jirka Š's, but since I'd already written it I went ahead and posted it anyway.

Comment: Also, this will work if your string has more `-` like `String1-number-String2-String3-number-String4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a XPath 1.0/2.0 string function solution (not regex) that will work for the 'String1-number-String2' example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after('String1-number-String2','-'), '-')"/>
```

---edit---

I seem to have misunderstood. That string function will return 'number', not 'String1-number'.

Here is an XPath 2.0 solution that will return 'String1-number':

```
<xsl:variable name="substrings" select="tokenize('String1-number-String2','-')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($substrings[1], '-', $substrings[2])"/>
```